# Batch download of URLs from command line multithreaded

Tags: command-line, bash, wget, curl, gnu-parallel

I have 100,000 URLs of small files to download. Would like to use 10 threads and pipelining is a must. I concatenate the result to one file. Current approach is:

```
cat URLS | xargs -P5 -- curl >> OUTPUT
```

Is there a better option that will show progress of the whole operation? Must work from the command line.

Comment: "Would like to use 10 threads and pipelining is a must. I concatenate the result to one file." So the order doesn't matter?

Comment: Use [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), it will even keep the order of the output. If you tag your question accordingly, you might be lucky and [the author](http://superuser.com/users/41337/ole-tange) might chime in ;-)

Comment: Order is not an issue. Tagged for gnu-parallel good idea. Is it possible to use parallel and still get the pipelining in curl?

Comment: Don't you get the files intermingled when you do that? Unless your webserver is single-threaded, I don't see how you would avoid having two processes writing simultaneously to your output file.

Comment: Mangling, jumbling are all not a problem for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat URLS | parallel -k -P10 curl >> OUTPUT
```

or if progress is more important:

```
cat URLS | parallel -k -P10 --eta curl >> OUTPUT
```

or:

```
cat URLS | parallel -k -P10 --progress curl >> OUTPUT
```

The 10 seconds installation will try do to a full installation; if
that fails, a personal installation; if that fails, a minimal
installation.

```
wget -O - pi.dk/3 | sh
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Comment: I had tried this installer `wget -O - pi.dk/3 | sh` but seem to have gotten some lame excuse for parallel that really does nothing: `parallel [OPTIONS] command -- arguments / for each argument, run command with argument, in parallel`

Comment: Ah, I had to uninstall moreutils first. `apt-get remove moreutils`